# Get remaining storage on Google photos

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-photos, google-photos-api

It might be really simple but I cannot figure it out. I made a little script that is able to upload some photos/video using rest API.

Since they all count towards the storage quota (15gb free) I would like to query the remaining free space.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

### You can retrieve your storage quota with the method [About:get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get?apix_params=%7B%22fields%22%3A%22storageQuota%22%7D), setting the query parameter `fields` to `storageQuota`

This will give you the following information:

[image]

Your remaining quota can be calculated as "limit" - "usage", in my case around 1,5 GB which is in agreement with the information I can see from the user interface in Google Drive and Google Photos.

Comment: but this doesn't give the actual remaining storage for google photos quota. I have just gone to google drive and I can see I have about 12gb remaining. When i go to google photos > settings I can see that there is ~5gb remaining until i have to either delete or "recover storage" I want the 5gb value, not the 12gb remaining which is what the drive api v3 is giving me

Comment: I updated my answer and hope that it is clearer now. I do not understand what you mean having 12 GB remaining on Google Drive and 5 GB on Google Photos. As you mentioned yourself - both count towards a common quota.